# Visual Studio 2017 OData Connected Service endpoint relative path

Tags: visual-studio, odata-connected-service

I've added connected service to Visual Studio 2017 which points to the local metadata file. The problem is that I had to point to the absolute path to this metadata file e.g. C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\$metadata.xml, but I would like to keep relative path in the ConnectedService.json.

When I'm trying to change this to sth like:
"Endpoint": "~/Connected Services/OData Service/$metadata.xml",

I have an error:

[image]

Is there any way to specify relative path there? To keep metadata file in the solution and to make it working for all teammates?